# Which Bug Tracking tools can Beanstalk work with?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bug-tracking, beanstalk-svn

Which Bug Tracking tools can Beanstalk work with?

e.g. so that when I check in code, I can mark it with a bug reference and it will cross-reference for me.

edit: also interested in tools that can potentially be integrated using [Beanstalks Web hooks](http://help.beanstalkapp.com/faqs/integration-tools/trigger-a-url-on-commit-with-web-hooks) feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/)

[Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Beanstalk maintains a list [on their site](http://beanstalkapp.com/partners).